# Efficient algorithm to update a range of objects' properties

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

*(I'm not sure how to summarize this question in the title)*

I have a random number of class A objects with a couple of properties, including color. I then receive a random number of class B objects, which all have the color property. I need to update my range of class A objects to match both the color properties of the class B objects and the number of class B objects. Class A objects can either be removed, created or modified. Notably there may never exist two class A objects with the same color.

The simplest way would be to just remove all class A objects and then create new ones (the same number of class B objects) and set each newly created class A object's color property to match respective class B object's color property. However - performance-wise, it is a huge win to modify the color property of a class A object to match the color property of a class B object, instead of deleting a class A object and creating a new one.

The class A objects are initially contained in a map. The class B objects arrive in a vector.

I'm wondering if someone recognizes the problem and know some kind of elegant design pattern?

Comment: Is the map of class A objects a sorted map? What is the key?

Comment: If the order matters, this problem looks like finding the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance). If not, we may just count the number of class B objects having each color (using a map, for example, or an array if there are very few predefined colors). After that, count the number of class A objects having each color in the same fashion. Obviously, only the `min (#A:c, #B:c)` class A objects of each color `c` remain. All remaining class A objects can have their color reassigned.

Comment: @Gassa: It is currently a HashMap, with one arbitrary object property as key (but not the color property). However, there's room to change things here.

Comment: Notably there may never exist two class A objects with the same color.

Comment: Are class A and class B arbitrarily related only by the aspect of having a color property? How can an arbitrary property be a key for indexing into a hashmap? Given a particular class B object, is there some way of uniquely choosing the class A object whose color should be updated? It seems like something might possibly be missing from the question.

Comment: Yes - class A and class B are arbitrarily related only by the aspect of having a color property.

Comment: I simply mean that another property than color is used as key in the map.

Comment: @Atreys: Given a particular class B object, any one class A object may be updated to match the color property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested code but should work. Ir certainly demonstrates the *algorithm* (not pattern).

```
public void test() {
    // Start data.
    Map<String, A> asInAMap = new HashMap<>();
    // The B's arrive.
    List<B> arrivingBs = new ArrayList<>();
    // Grab the A's and key them on colour.
    Map<Colour, A> asInColour = new HashMap<>();
    // Keep track of all As.
    Set<A> availableAs = new HashSet<>(asInAMap.values());
    // Roll them into the Map.
    for (A a : availableAs) {
        // Key all A's by colour.
        asInColour.put(a.colour, a);
    }
    // Walk the Bs, matching up the A's
    Set<A> matchedAs = new HashSet<>();
    Set<B> unMatchedBs = new HashSet<>();
    for (B b : arrivingBs) {
        // Is there a matching A with the right colour?
        A aMatched = asInColour.get(b.colour);
        if (aMatched != null) {
            // Keep track of the ones that matched.
            matchedAs.add(aMatched);
        } else {
            // Keep track of all not-matched Bs.
            unMatchedBs.add(b);
        }
    }
    // Don't touch any of the matched ones.
    availableAs.removeAll(matchedAs);
    // Change colours of any A.s left.
    Iterator<B> bsWithNewColours = unMatchedBs.iterator();
    for (A changeAColour : availableAs) {
        if (bsWithNewColours.hasNext()) {
            B newB = bsWithNewColours.next();
            // Change a spare A's colour.
            changeAColour.colour = newB.colour;
            // Finished with that one.
            bsWithNewColours.remove();
        }
    }
    // All that are left in notMatched must generate new A's.
    for (B newColour : unMatchedBs) {
        // Make a new A with a non-matched colour.
        asInAMap.put(String.valueOf(newColour.colour), new A(newColour.colour));
    }
}
```

Essentially:

1. Make a list of all A's.
2. Index all As by colour.
3. For each B, if an A exists with the same colour, mark it as a keeper. If it does not, mark it for future attention.
4. For all remaining A's that did not match, change its colour to the colour of one of the marked B's and unmark the B.
5. For all remaining marked B's, there was no A matching it's colour and all available A's are exhausted so make new A's for them.